# Problem while trying to boot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

So I try to boot up and install Ubuntu 14.04.4 from a DVD and I get this error:

[image: screenshot of kernel output during boot]

Can someone help?

Comment: As its showing I/O error on /dev/sr0 which usually refers to your DVD Drive, I think your bootable DVD is buggy. Try booting from a USB Drive  [help](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Your DVD seems to be failing.

Answer (score 2):

Your DVD (or DVD drive) is dirty or broken. Please clean it or replace it. Or use a different medium type to install Ubuntu (e. g. a USB thumb drive).

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score 0):

Something or another is causing your computer to have trouble reading and/or using the DVD correctly. (could be a scratched DVD, a dirty/broken disc drive, or a corrupt ISO) Your best bet is to boot off of a medium that doesn't use your disc drive, i.e. a flash drive or SD card. If the problem persists, it is probably a corrupt ISO file.